# Object reference not set to an instance of an object when using a manual Textbox (Textbox tb = (Textbox))

Tags: c#, winforms, nullreferenceexception

I have 30 or so textboxes that I have labeled in order {ex: R1C1B1, R1C2B1, R2C1B1, ...}

Here is my code:

```
    private void Solve(int row, int column, int box)
    {
        string numbers = "123456789";
        TextBox newTextBox = (TextBox)Controls.Find(string.Format("tbox{0}", "R" + row.ToString() + "C" + column.ToString() + "B" + box.ToString()), false).FirstOrDefault();

        MessageBox.Show(newTextBox.Text);

        if (newTextBox.Text != "")
         {
            return;
         }

        numbers = numbers.Replace(checkRow(row, column), "");
        numbers = numbers.Replace(checkColumn(row, column), "");
        numbers = numbers.Replace(checkBoxPos(row, column), "");

        if (numbers.Length == 1)
         {
            newTextBox.Text = numbers;
         }
    }
```

Whenever I try to use MessageBox.Show to view what is in the textbox I get the error in the title. Here is all of the error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in SudokuSolver.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check whether `newTextBox` is not null before accessing it. If there is no textbox with given name, then `FirstOrDefault` will return `null` as default value:

```
var name = String.Format("tboxR{0}C{1}B{2}", row, column, box);
TextBox newTextBox = (TextBox)Controls.Find(name, false).FirstOrDefault();

if (newTextBox != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show(newTextBox.Text);
    //...
}
```

Remember, if `newTextBox` is `null` then you cannot get it's text - `null.Text` will give you `NullReferenceException`.

BTW you can use LINQ to search controls

```
var textBox = Controls.OfType<TextBox>().FirstOrDefault(tb => tb.Name == name);
```

Comment: Thanks I changed the false to true and made it null and it all worked

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `newTextBox.Text != ""` use `newTextBox != null && newTextBox.Text != ""`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
private void Solve(int row, int column, int box)
    {
        string numbers = "123456789";
        TextBox newTextBox = (TextBox)Controls.Find(string.Format("tbox{0}", "R" + row.ToString() + "C" + column.ToString() + "B" + box.ToString()), false).FirstOrDefault();

         if(newTextBox!=null)
         {
             MessageBox.Show(newTextBox.Text);
             return;
         }

        numbers = numbers.Replace(checkRow(row, column), "");
        numbers = numbers.Replace(checkColumn(row, column), "");
        numbers = numbers.Replace(checkBoxPos(row, column), "");

        if (numbers.Length == 1)
         {
            newTextBox.Text = numbers;
         }
    }
```

You need to check the value of `newTextBox` before using it. You need to check if the value inside `newTextBox` is `null`.

Comment: @CodeCaster:- That makes sense. People can leave a comment like you after downvoting. Constructive criticizm is always good! Thanks